# Aggregate hourly means based on compound field expression

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, compound-key

I am trying to calculate the hourly mean of `x` in a data frame similar to this:

```
  min hour day month year    x
1  10   22  31    12 2013 18.3
2  30   22  31    12 2013 16.5
3  50   22  31    12 2013 15.7
4  10   23  31    12 2013 16.7
5  30   23  31    12 2013 18.0
6  50   23  31    12 2013 18.1
7  10    0   1     1 2014 17.4
8  30    0   1     1 2014 15.4
9  50    0   1     1 2014 16.9
```

I have tried different things with the `aggregate` function but without luck. So what I want is to calculate the mean of `x` if the value of `hour`, `day`, `month`, `year` are the same. The output should be like below:

```
  hour day month year        x
1   22  31    12 2013 16.83333
2   23  31    12 2013 17.60000
3    0   1     1 2014 16.56667
```

Comment: `aggregate(x ~ hour + day + month + year , data=dat, mean, na.rm=T)` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try..

```
require(dplyr)

mydf %>%
   group_by(year, month, day, hour) %>%
   summarise (average = mean(x))
```